# typescript-plugin-css-modules not working with @use rule inside scss module

Tags: typescript, sass, create-react-app, css-modules

I have a SCSS module inside a Create React App project. I installed `typescript-plugin-css-modules` in order for Typescript to be able to "type" my module. I import it in my React component like this :

```
import s from "./core/layoutSidebar.module.scss";
```

Everything is working as expected as far as i don't import my variables into the module with the @use rule :

```
@use "style/helpers/variables";
```

If so, Typescript type the `s` imported module as an empty interface `{}` which makes my IDE throwing errors on my classNames.

Even if I only use the variables syntaxe (eg : `$spacing-1`) the same error happens again

Comment: This has been [reported as a bug on that module](https://github.com/mrmckeb/typescript-plugin-css-modules/issues/152)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any fix. Time to look for another plugin I'd say. Maybe have a look at postcss

Comment: Also worth noting that that npm package hasn't had any [sizeable changes made since last year](https://github.com/mrmckeb/typescript-plugin-css-modules/graphs/contributors). This is what happens with small not well supported npm packages

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug in the package. There's nothing anyone can do about it here

Comment: Thanks for the response @liam, my bad I missed the open issue. I'm closing the question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Liam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542251/liam) I figured out that the problem has already been reported as a [bug](https://github.com/mrmckeb/typescript-plugin-css-modules/issues/152) on the repo.